# javascript animation onclick function and javascript session

Tags: javascript, animation

im trying to write a javascript function that works similar to this:

btn.onClick (play audio.mp3, img expand 15%, delay X millisecond, img deflate to original size)

then if not clicked for Y milliseconds (disable on click function, play img animation fall and fade for 2 seconds)

then open index.html

also, is it possible to save an array session within javascript, between multiple html?

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer variables between js files using [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).